# How to used sd2 primitivies and sdl2_gfx in c4droid

Tags: android, c++, c, ide

How to used sd2 primitivies and sdl2_gfx in c4droid
In sdl copiler options i have
-lSDL2_image -lSDL2_net -ltiff -ljpeg -lpng -lz -lSDL2_ttf -lfreetype -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_test -lsmpeg2 -lvorbisfile -lvorbis -logg -lstdc++ -lSDL2 -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -landroid -I(c4droid:GCCROOT)(c4droid:PREFIX)/include/SDL2 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared
When i add *.h file and lib c4droid do not have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stiupid it is very simple download SDL2_gfx source extension for example from http://www.ferzkopp.net/wordpress/2016/01/02/sdl_gfx-sdl2_gfx/ add SDL2_gfxPrimitives.c and SDL2_rotozoom.c to compile and to directory and add to directory SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h, SDL2_rotozoom.h, SDL2_gfxPrimitives_font.h. To multifile compilation hold compile button and set compile multiple source code files